# mvc regex replace array of pattern on one sentence

Tags: c#, regex, model-view-controller

I want to replace certain words in one sentence string with regex replace.

For it, I create pattern array :

```
string[] words = {"abc","132","qwe","bold","test"};
```

and for replace, I do it :

```
foreach (string item in words){
    output = Regex.Replace(output,@"\b" + item + "\b", " ");
}
```

but this way don't work ...

Someone has an idea?

**Explanation**

I use the above method in VB.net and will respond without problems.

I am a beginner in C #

Comment: Please show the value of `output` and explain what isn't working

Comment: Use `output = Regex.Replace(output, @$"(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(item)}(?!\w)", " ");` once you happen to have special chars in your `item`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you forgot the `@` literal at the second `\b`:

either put it in there

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\b" + item + @"\b", " ");
```

or double the backslash so it is used as an escape character:

```
output = Regex.Replace(output, @"\b" + item + "\\b", " ");
```

Comment: thanks so much. My problem has been resolved

Comment: @user3150241 you are welcome. But Wiktor found a perfect duplicate which has a much more profound answer